# a4j support : reRender not working in IE10

Tags: ajax4jsf

We use JSF and a4j in our project. We have got code as below. But, the reRender doesn't work in IE 10 browser. While accessing the application using  IE 10 browser, ot able to render the div with the id, 'designDirectorId'. Could anyone help please?

```
<a4j:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true" immediate="true" actionListener="{applicationRequestHandler.regionChangeListner}"
reRender="designDirectorId" />
```

Thanks in advance,
Venkat

Comment: Are you certain your id `designDirectorId` is unique on the page?  Different browsers handle id collisions differently which could explain why this happens in IE10...

Comment: Yes. The id designDirectorId is unique on the page

Answer (score 0):

We exactly have the same problem.
When turning on the compatibility view in IE10, everything works normal again.

For now, we are going to solve the problem by adding the meta tag  in de head of the html.